# Why is fwrite writing strange things?

Tags: c, printf, byte, fwrite

So here's what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

FILE *fin;
struct STR {
    float d;
    int x;
} testing;

testing.d = 11.12;
testing.x = 31121;


    fin = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    //fprintf(fin,"%7.4f %7d\n",testing.d,testing.x);
    fwrite(&testing, sizeof(struct STR),1,fin);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

So what happens when I compile and run? I get this:

```
"…ë1A‘y  "
```

When I comment out the `fwrite` and use the `fprintf`, I get this:

```
"11.1200   31121"
```

Can someone explain this to me? I tried running it on windows and on linux, and both times the output was obscure.

Also, I guess while we're on the subject, how come the size of the text file with "11.1200   31121" is 16 bytes? I thought that integers (on a 32-bit machine) were 4 bytes each? Is it 16 bytes because there are 16 total characters in the txt file?

Thanks

Comment: `fprintf ()` convert numbers to human readable format according to the type of the number (int, float, .. etc), while `fwrite()` write number in binary format, exactly how it is stored in memory, when you use `fwrite()` to save struct, you use `fread()` to read into the struct, no need to do conversions. but `fprintf `you will have to do some conversions from text back to binary format, and this conversion is handled by the functions `sscanf()` and similar

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file as a text file but you are writing binary data, it's not human readable. To read it properly you need `fread()`. Instead `fprintf()` writes text as you can check.

So

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

struct STR {
    float d;
    int x;
} testing;

int main()
{

    FILE *file;
    testing.d = 11.12;
    testing.x = 31121;


    file = fopen("output.txt", "wb");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&testing, sizeof(struct STR), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    file = fopen("output.txt", "rb");
    if ((file != NULL) && (fread(&testing, sizeof(struct STR), 1, file) == 1))
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%f -- %d\n", testing.d, testing.x);
        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

As iharob said, you’re writing binary data that are getting interpreted as nonsense characters in the current locale, not human-readable ASCII.  In addition, the reason your compiler is allocating sixteen bytes to the structure is padding.  The reason the compiler is padding to 16 bytes is that your CPU has special instructions to index arrays of structures more efficiently when their size is a small power of two.

If you really want to serialize your data in a portable binary format, or transmit it over a network, you should both use an exact-width type such as `int32_t` rather than `int` (which has been 16, 32 or 64 bits and might have other widths than those) and also convert to a specific endianness rather than whatever the native byte order happens to be.  The classic solution is `htonl()`.  Also, write out each field separately to avoid problems with padding, or use a compiler extension to pack your structure and turn padding off.